# Physical significance of orbital stability

Tags: schroedinger-equation, stability, chaos-theory, complex-systems, non-linear-schroedinger

I saw the orbital stability in [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_stability), I just understand it from mathematics angle. But in physical, what is its mean?   Since I saw many paper talk about the stability of Schrödinger equation, I think it should has some physical significance.

Comment: If electron orbits were not stable, atoms couldn't exist

Comment: @Triatticus  Very interesting,  could you detail talk it ? I just a student of math with little physical knowledge.

Comment: I was just supplying an example, but im using a mobile device and cant apply a longer answer. Another good one is what would happen if earths orbit wasnt stable. Hopefully someone can give you a nice comprehensive answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following answer is aimed at providing an intuitive sense of the meaning of a stable orbit, not at being precise.

"Stability" refers to a condition that a system will return to despite small perturbations from that condition.  A very simple example is a marble at the bottom of a bowl: the marble will return to the bottom any time it is displaced from the bottom.

A more complex example is a marble at the bottom of a bowl shaped like half of a torus (a donut shape) sliced the long way.  The marble can roll around in a circle, and if that circular "orbit" is perturbed, the marble will soon return to its circular motion.

An electron *orbital* is stable if all the lower-energy orbitals are occupied by electrons. If the electron is given a very slight push (not enough to transfer it to a higher-energy orbital) by an outside influence, it will return to its stable orbital as soon as the influence is removed.